# Crash while unwinding to the root controller from multiple custom segues

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I need to implement custom segues that may stack up to three times and unwind back through whole stack to root view controller.

Here is code for my segue:

```
- (void)perform {

    UIViewController* sourceViewController = self.sourceViewController;

    UIView* firstVCView = [(UIViewController*)self.sourceViewController view];
    UIView* secondVCView = [(UIViewController*)self.destinationViewController view];

    // Get the screen width and height.
    CGFloat screenWidth = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width;
    CGFloat screenHeight = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height;

    // Specify the initial position of the destination view.
    secondVCView.frame = CGRectMake(screenWidth, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight);

    // Access the app's key window and insert the destination view above the current (source) one.
    UIWindow* window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;

    [window insertSubview:secondVCView aboveSubview:firstVCView];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        firstVCView.frame = CGRectOffset(firstVCView.frame, -screenWidth, 0);
        secondVCView.frame = CGRectOffset(secondVCView.frame, -screenWidth, 0);
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [sourceViewController.navigationController presentViewController:self.destinationViewController animated:NO completion:nil];
    }];
}
```

And for unwind segue:

```
- (void)perform {

    UIViewController* sourceViewController = self.sourceViewController;

    UIView* secondView = [(UIViewController*)self.sourceViewController view];
    UIView* firstView = [(UIViewController*)self.destinationViewController view];

    CGFloat screenWidth = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width;

    UIWindow* window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;

    [window insertSubview:firstView aboveSubview:secondView];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        firstView.frame = CGRectOffset(firstView.frame, screenWidth, 0);
        secondView.frame = CGRectOffset(secondView.frame, screenWidth, 0);
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [sourceViewController.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];

    }];
}
```

Everything works fine for single transition - I could easily go forward and unwind back as well.
But when I do two or more transitions forward and try to unwind back afterwards following error is occurred right when I push button associated with unwind segue even before any code calls:

```
2015-08-28 18:40:37.460 ProjectName[17807:973012] *** -[UIStoryboardUnwindSegueTemplate performSelector:withObject:withObject:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x7fbd4bc717d0
```

Obviously its the last controller lost. 
But if I lock it and whole previous stack of controllers in memory then nothing happens except method call "prepareForSegue": no other delegate methods called, no exceptions thrown, no transitions performed. 
Also when all controllers locked in memory I tried to call popToRootViewControllerAnimated and other similar methods - no result at all as well.

I ran out of ideas how to fix it and read whole internet for solutions. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trouble was in the custom segue in this line:

```
[sourceViewController.navigationController presentViewController:self.destinationViewController animated:NO completion:nil];
```

I should pushViewController instead of presentViewController:

```
[sourceViewController.navigationController pushViewController:self.destinationViewController animated:NO];
```

Now when I changed it everything works like a charm. Hope it helps someone.